# Need to increase box wider using CSS but changing width and length gives no effect

Tags: html, css

I have a simple webpage for my terms and conditions section that uses CSS.

However, I cannot make the **blueBox** wider or longer.

I tried to adjust the height and width using CSS but width and length are not changing. Can you help me out?

Here is the index page.

```
<div id="mainContentArea">
    <div id="contentBox">
        <div id="title">BlueBliss Inc.</div>
        <div id="linkGroup">
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="blueBox"> 
          <div id="header"></div>
          <div class="contentTitle">Welcome to BlueBliss Inc.</div>
            <div class="pageContent">
              <p>This template was created for those needing a really simple site, without much content.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer mi. Vivamus sit amet neque vitae sapien bibendum sodales. Curabitur elementum. Duis imperdiet. Donec eleifend porttitor sapien. Praesent leo. Quisque auctor velit sed tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean laoreet imperdiet nunc. Donec commodo suscipit dolor. Aenean nibh. Sed id odio. Aliquam lobortis risus ut felis. Sed vehicula pellentesque quam.</p>
              <p>Vestibulum augue quam, interdum id, congue semper, convallis non, velit. Quisque augue tortor, tristique ac, scelerisque eget, aliquam id, sem. Aenean lorem. Fusce velit nibh, dapibus quis, laoreet nec, porta a, dui. Nullam ac urna. Proin eget elit. Nunc scelerisque venenatis urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce congue, turpis ut commodo mattis, pede erat fringilla tellus, pulvinar suscipit odio lorem sed pede.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.aszx.net">web development</a> by <a href="http://www.bryantsmith.com">bryant smith</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 99%;
}
body{
  height: 99%;
}
#mainContentArea{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
  display: table; 
  height: 100%;  
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 600px;
}
.link,.linkActive{
  width:75px;
  margin-right:10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top:24px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background-image:url(tab.gif);
  position:relative; bottom:0px;
}
#linkGroup{
  margin-right:10px;
  height:40px;
  width:600px;
}
#title{
  width:230px;
  height:40px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-top:15px;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
.contentTitle{
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:12px;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  width:573px;
}
.pageContent{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  width:560px;
  height:auto;
}
#blueBox{
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color:#E7EDF8;
  width:600px;
  clear:both;
  height:auto;
}
#header{
  width:600px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  background-image:url(header.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#footer{
  width:600px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  background-image:url(footer.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
  padding-right:10px;
}
#contentBox{
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

Also, its limiting me to stay on its size. its not giving me the option to scroll down. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have this `<div id="mainContentArea">` which has 
`#mainContentArea {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;   display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 661px;
}`

the problem is that your `#blueBox` is inside the `#mainContentArea` division, which has the property overflow set to hidden. So no matter how much you add to the `#blueBox` it will be hidden by `#mainContentArea`

**Solution** : remove the `overflow:hidden` line, you dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined maximum available width at parent element:

```
#mainContentArea{
    width: 600px;
}
```

So you have not the option to go further from this **600px** in width. If you want to set the width of **blueBox** to a value more than 600px, you should increase it on **#mainContentArea** element.

Also it would be far more better to hesitate from defining `width` property for every single element. So, please remove `width` declaration from these elements:

```
#linkGroup
#blueBox
#header
.contentTitle
.pageContent
```

At the end, you dont need to declare `position: absolute` for **#blueBox**, so remove it. Likewise, this part of your CSS

```
html{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 99%;
}
body{
  height: 99%;
}
```

is more likely to be removed, if there is no special need for it to remain, as it could cause problems with your simple structure.

```css
#mainContentArea{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto; 
  display: table; 
  height: 100%;  
  position: relative; 
  width: 600px;
}

.link,.linkActive{
  width:75px;
  margin-right:10px;
  float: left;
  margin-top:24px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  background-image:url(tab.gif);
  position:relative; bottom:0px;
}

.link:hover{
  background-image:url(tab2.gif);
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.link a{
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#linkGroup{
  margin-right:10px;
  height:40px;
}

#title
{
  width:230px;
  height:40px;
  margin-right:20px;
  margin-top:15px;
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}

.contentTitle
{
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#213E74;
  font-size:19px;
  margin-left:15px;
  margin-right:12px;
  margin-bottom:12px;
}

.pageContent
{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#000000;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-right:20px;
  height:auto;
}


#blueBox{
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color:#E7EDF8;
}

#header{
  height:20px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  background-image:url(header.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#footer{
  height:20px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  background-image:url(footer.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
  padding-right:10px;
  color:#BDCDEC;
}
#footer a{
  font-size:9px;
  color:#BDCDEC;
}

#contentBox
{
  margin-top:25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContentArea">
    <div id="contentBox">
        <div id="title">BlueBliss Inc.</div>

        <div id="linkGroup">
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="blueBox"> 
          <div id="header"></div>
          <div class="contentTitle">Welcome to BlueBliss Inc.</div>
            <div class="pageContent">
              <p>This template was created for those needing a really simple site, without much content.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer mi. Vivamus sit amet neque vitae sapien bibendum sodales. Curabitur elementum. Duis imperdiet. Donec eleifend porttitor sapien. Praesent leo. Quisque auctor velit sed tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean laoreet imperdiet nunc. Donec commodo suscipit dolor. Aenean nibh. Sed id odio. Aliquam lobortis risus ut felis. Sed vehicula pellentesque quam.</p>
              <p>Vestibulum augue quam, interdum id, congue semper, convallis non, velit. Quisque augue tortor, tristique ac, scelerisque eget, aliquam id, sem. Aenean lorem. Fusce velit nibh, dapibus quis, laoreet nec, porta a, dui. Nullam ac urna. Proin eget elit. Nunc scelerisque venenatis urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce congue, turpis ut commodo mattis, pede erat fringilla tellus, pulvinar suscipit odio lorem sed pede.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.aszx.net">web development</a> by <a href="http://www.bryantsmith.com">bryant smith</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it shows the scrollbar but still it is limited. it cannot scroll down.

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod please check my updated answer, and see if the given code snippet, generates the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your css so that it can be responsive, it is great to work with reponsive divs. try

```css
#mainContentArea{
 width:100%;
  
 
 
}

.link,.linkActive
{
width:75px;
margin-right:10px;
float: left;
margin-top:24px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
background-image:url(tab.gif);
position:relative; bottom:0px;
}

.link:hover
{
background-image:url(tab2.gif);
}

a
{
text-decoration:none;
}

.link a{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
}

#linkGroup
{
margin-right:10px;
height:40px;
width:100%;
}

#title
{
width:200px;;
height:40px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-top:15px;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
float:left;
}

.contentTitle
{
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#213E74;
font-size:19px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-right:12px;
margin-bottom:12px;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}

.pageContent
{
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#000000;
font-size:12px;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
width:90%;
height:auto;
}


#blueBox
{
    position: relative;
  
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#E7EDF8;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    height:auto;
}

#header
{
width:100%;
height:20px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
background-image:url(header.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#footer
{
width:100%;
height:20px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
background-image:url(footer.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-align:center;
padding-right:10px;
color:#BDCDEC;
}
#footer a
{
font-size:9px;
color:#BDCDEC;
}

#contentBox
{
margin-top:25px;
}



html, body {
text-align: center;
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
}
p {text-align: left;}
```

```html
 <head>
<title>Blue Bliss by Bryant Smith</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bluebliss.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="mainContentArea">
    <div id="contentBox">
        <div id="title">BlueBliss Inc.</div>

        <div id="linkGroup">
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">About</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></div>
            <div class="link"><a href="index.html">Contact</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="blueBox"> 
          <div id="header"></div>
          <div class="contentTitle">Welcome to BlueBliss Inc.</div>
            <div class="pageContent">
              <p>This template was created for those needing a really simple site, without much content.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer mi. Vivamus sit amet neque vitae sapien bibendum sodales. Curabitur elementum. Duis imperdiet. Donec eleifend porttitor sapien. Praesent leo. Quisque auctor velit sed tellus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean laoreet imperdiet nunc. Donec commodo suscipit dolor. Aenean nibh. Sed id odio. Aliquam lobortis risus ut felis. Sed vehicula pellentesque quam.</p>
              <p>Vestibulum augue quam, interdum id, congue semper, convallis non, velit. Quisque augue tortor, tristique ac, scelerisque eget, aliquam id, sem. Aenean lorem. Fusce velit nibh, dapibus quis, laoreet nec, porta a, dui. Nullam ac urna. Proin eget elit. Nunc scelerisque venenatis urna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce congue, turpis ut commodo mattis, pede erat fringilla tellus, pulvinar suscipit odio lorem sed pede.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.aszx.net">web development</a> by <a href="http://www.bryantsmith.com">bryant smith</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you put`#mainContentArea` `width: 600px;` you change the `width` then you will get your specification. because `#blueBox` is under the `#mainContentArea`. Then you can adjust the `#blueBox` height and width.

Comment: Remove the code `overflow: hidden;` under the `html` and change the `overflow: hidden;` as `overflow: scroll;` under the `#mainContentArea`

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all remove the  "position: absolute;" from the #blueBox
add "height: 100%" to the following selectors a) #blueBox b) #contentBox.

Find sample Code bellow!!

```
.pageContent {
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     color:#000000;
     font-size:12px;
     margin-left:20px;
     margin-right:20px;
     width:560px;
     height:100%;
    }

#bluebox {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color:#E7EDF8;
    width:600px;
    clear:both;
    height:100%;
   overflow-y: scroll; /*Allow you to scroll inside the blue content*/
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have restricted the width of your inner div just keep the width of inner divs to 100% and it will expand. hope it will work